# Access denied After MySQL Manual Installation on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Somehow I wanted to install MySQL manually, so I did as explained in [How to Set Up MySQL on Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/setup-mysql) except that I didn't need to create a VM instance because I already have one.

That is, since my OS is 'Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)', I executed the following two commands to install MySQL:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

and

```
$ sudo apt-get -y install mysql-server
```

There's no errors in this step and I created a root password by the following command:

```
$ sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

But when I tried to connect to MySQL, (entering the root password I created)

```
$ mysql --user=root --password
```

I've got

```
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

What would be a problem here and what should I check in order to connect to MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error on the tutorial. In order to connect to the MySQL you should run:

```
$ sudo mysql --user=root --password
```